# jQuery Mobile splash screen for all devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, splash-screen

How can I display a splash screen in my jQuery Mobile app until the head scripts have finished downloading?

I know that on Apple devices, you can add something like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/loading-splash.png">
```

I'd like something similar, but that works on all platforms. I don't want to display the body until all head scripts have loaded, because it looks ugly. Is there possibly an alternative to putting all the scripts in head that achieves the same goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out any of the following links:

- http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons
- https://gist.github.com/472519

Both will both tell you the apple-start-up-image will only work on iOS devices (and it's not so easy to get them to show, too).

I guess it will take a while until splash-screens become available across platforms.

In the meantime I'm using this in my page head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){var a;if(navigator.platform==="iPad"){ 
      a = window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90 ? 
        "FULLPATH-TO-landscape.jpg":"FULLPATH-TO-portrait.jpg"
      } else { 
        a = window.devicePixelRatio === 2 ? 
          "FULLPATH-TO-retina.jpg" : "FULLPATH-TO-startup.jpg"
           }
   document.write('<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="'+a+'"/>')})()
 </script>
```

Of course you can also write plain HTML, but I found this snippet somewhere in [Mobile Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile), with the author arguing that all provided splash sceens will be loaded on all devices. By scripting it like this you only get a single splash-screen image and save 3 http requests plus loading unnecessary images.

Comment: thanks for the answer. what width and height do your images have?

Comment: hm... currently I'm using 4 different images sizes depending on screen size, but I also switched to injecting the background image into my first CSS stylesheet plus setting `background-size: 100%; background-size: cover` to stretch the image to cover the whole screen. I can post an example tonight (don't have the code here). Works really nice.